# unable to push helm package archive to artifactory using Helm Push Artifactory Plugin

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I have been trying to publish an artifact created by **helm package** command to artifactory.
I setup the environment on my local **Windows 10** laptop by installing the **helm client**.
I am able to create chart archives through **helm package** command. 
After the package creation I tried to publish the package to a artifactory repo(**local artifactory pro instance**).

It is required by Helm that the repository where the package needs to be pushed be added as a repo via **helm repo add**  command. But before executing the **helm repo add** command, the artifactory repo should be configured as a **Helm Chart Repository** at the time of repo creation.
After the successful execution of **helm repo add** I tried to push the archive to that artifactory location. 
https://github.com/belitre/helm-push-artifactory-plugin is the plugin I am using to publish the archive to artifactory. However, I keep getting error once I execute command **helm push-artifactory** :

```
    Error: 400: could not properly parse response JSON: 
    HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
    Type Status Report
    Message Invalid URI
    Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

Please guide. let me know in case I missed out on any important details.

**EDIT 1 : START**

**Command for adding repo :**

```
helm repo add helm-chart-artifcatory-repo http://localhost:8081/artifactory/helm-chart-artifactory-repo/ --username myadminusername --password myadminpass
"helm-chart-artifcatory-repo" has been added to your repositories
```

**Command for pushing to artifactory :**

```
helm push-artifactory xyz-demofile-0.1.1.tgz http://localhost:8081/artifactory/helm-chart-artifactory-repo --username myadminusername --password myadminpass
```

**EDIT 1 : END**

Comment: Please share the full command that you're running.

Comment: @mario I have updated my OP with full commands under EDIT 1

Comment: What version of [helm-push-artifactory-plugin](https://github.com/belitre/helm-push-artifactory-plugin) have you installed ? What is your version of **helm** ? Could you  run `helm push-artifactory` command with verbose output enabled by adding `--debug` flag ?